# Issue adding jQuery to single product page in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have an issue loading jQuery on the WooCommerce single product page.

I need to make a dynamic onclick change with jQuery: adding: `'border: xx xx xx'` to the `.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper` css class.

My code:

**Hook (placed in WooCommerce functions.php):**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'jquery_script_after_single_product_summary' );
function jquery_script_after_single_product_summary() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //**START CHANGE FRAME PRODUCT PAGE**//
                    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  $("select.frame").change(function() {
                    var changeframe = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                    $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').css('border', changeframe);
                  });
                });
    //END CHANGE FRAME PRODUCT PAGE**//
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**Html selector to make onclick change (placed on the single product page):**

```
    <select class="frame">
<option value="">Choose frame</option>
<option value="">Without frame</option>
            <option value="20px solid black">Red</option>
            <option value="20px solid blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="20px solid purple">Yellow</option>
        </select>

<br><br><br>
<figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
```

---

What could be the issue? It works on online simulations but not in WordPress (WooCommerce). Am I placing the script in the wrong place or perhaps not loading a correct jQuery script file...?

I'm not using any Cache.

Any advice?

Comment: Is there any output on devtools console when you trying the "onchange" event ? (Dont have skills with WP, but it may help a bit to understand where is the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the console tab in your browser with your existing code, you will see the following error message

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $ is not a function TypeError: $ is not a
> function

---

The code below will solve that problem. The display of the HTML (drop-down list) can be applied anywhere on the page via template overrides or via the desired hook.

In this answer I have combined both in one

```php
function action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary() {
    // Display drop-down list
    echo '<select class="frame">
            <option value="">Choose frame</option>
            <option value="">Without frame</option>
            <option value="20px solid red">Red</option>
            <option value="20px solid blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="20px solid yellow">Yellow</option>
          </select>';
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // On change
        $( 'select.frame' ).change( function() {
            var changeframe = $(this).children( 'option:selected' ).val();
            
            // DEBUG
            console.log(changeframe);
            
            // Add border
            $( '.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper' ).css( 'border', changeframe );
        });          
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Holy moly. Thank you so much. You just beat Google.